# How to ensure initial values are set for properties of a class exposed via a webservice

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, asmx

I have a class which initializes its properties in its constructor.

```
public class Criteria
{
    public bool Chapter1 { get; set; }
    public bool Chapter2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public uint MaxResults { get; set; }
    public int Hits { get; set; }

    public Criteria()
    {
        Chapter1 = false;
        Chapter2 = false;
        ...
        MaxResults = 100;
        Hits = -1;
    }
}
```

This class is used internally within a web-service to configure searches on a DB.  When I construct the class internally, the correct initialization is performed and operation is as anticipated.

However, the class is also exposed as a parameter in a Method to this Web-Service :

```
    [WebMethod]
    public List<xxx> GetxxxCollection(string requestingUserName, Criteria sc)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Prior to the clients call to this web-service, the Criteria object is constructed and configured.  But, because its exposed through the web-service, the constructor is not actually called and the client does not always set all required values correctly.

Given that we have limited control over the client code, Whats the best strategy to ensure that appropriate initial values are set ?

Comment: It's been a while since I used those basic web services, but IIRC, isn't the parameterless constructor called before deserializing it? Regardless, instead of setting them in the constructor, your properties can have backing fields with their initial values set there on the field declaration. EDIT: But if it's true that the default constructor _is_ running, then maybe you need to double-check the data being sent: perhaps you are not sending the correct information.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: The client will be responsible for properly initializing the object.  If the client doesn't have sufficient knowledge to do so, then you will need to rethink your approach/redesign your application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the client in any way. The "Service" class on the client is in no way related to the service class that contains the constructor. It's just a "proxy" class, not the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the `nullable` fields, so that you know client hasn't set any value in the fields.

Comment: -1: Have you ever tries a nullable value type in an ASMX service? And what if the client has set the value to null?

Comment: No I haven't thats why I say maybe, `null` can be equal to NOT set, provided if `null` itself is not a value. Which is NOT clear yet

Answer (score 0):

Don't use auto-implemented properties in your class, but instead use the old manual properties with backing-fields which ***might*** be initialized by default without a constructor invocation:

```
public class Criteria
{
  private int _maxResults = 100;

  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

  public int MaxResults
  {
    get{ return _maxResult; }
    set{ _maxResults = value; }
  }

}
```

Comment: I checked this thing, it is NOT initialized to 100, value was 0.